# angular link tag uses custom service

Tags: angularjs

My app uses ngRoute, so when a link is tapped the page is injected in the ngView.
Thus I take advantage of the page controller so that when the page is visited it fires "TogglerFactory" service .
How can I call menuToggle() of this service whenever the link is tapped not only the first time the page is visited.  Thanks

```js
//---routing.js----------------------------------
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('appModule')
        .config(['$routeProvider', routing]);

    function routing ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/page1', {
            url: "/page1",
            templateUrl: 'views/page1.html',
            controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
        })
            .when('/page2', {
                url: "/page2",
                templateUrl: 'views/page2.html',
                controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
            })
    }
})();

//---menuToggle.js----------------------------------
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('appModule')
        .factory('TogglerFactory', function($rootScope) {
            var TogglerFactory = {};

            TogglerFactory.menuToggle = function(){
                $rootScope.clicked = !$rootScope.clicked;
            }

            return TogglerFactory;
        });
}());


//---page1Ctrl.js----------------------------------
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('appModule')
        .controller('Page1Ctrl', ['TogglerFactory', page1Ctrl]);

    function page1Ctrl(Toggler) {
        Toggler.menuToggle();
    }
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="appModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <base href="http://localhost:63342/students/">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script src="services/routing.js"></script>
    <script src="services/menuToggle.js"></script>

    <script src="controllers/menuToggleCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/mainMenuCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/page1Ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/page2Ctrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header ng-controller="MenuToggleCtrl">
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" ng-model="clicked" ng-click="menuToggle()">&#9776;</button>
    <label id="pageTitle" class="pageTitle">Select item from list</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section class="mainMenu" ng-controller="MainMenuCtrl" ng-if="!clicked">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <a href="#/{{item.name}}">
                <image ng-src="images/{{item.image}}.png"></image>
                {{item.name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>

<main ng-view></main>

<footer ng-controller="MenuToggleCtrl" ng-if="clicked">
    <ul class="horizontal-style">
        <li><button type="button">NO</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">YES</button></li>
    </ul>
</footer>

</body>
</html>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: What does it mean 'fires "TogglerFactory" service'? You don't initialize anything in there, you just define a function that can be called from wherever the service is injected. Do you mean calling TogglerFactory.menuToggle() when a click is preformed?

Comment: exactly.  I will edit the post to explain "fire" ;) sorry.