# Using angular routeProvider with controller

Tags: angularjs

Please consider the this code where the routeProvider is needed to inject page(n).html in ng-view.

In addition to the console error:

> unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider <- $routeProvider

The argument to function routeIt is the name of the page to navigate to, How can I mix a conditional switch with routeProvider.when in order to call the page matching the argument in the most efficient manner? Thanks

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('appModule')
        .controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'TogglerFactory', '$routeProvider',  MainMenuCtrl]);

    function MainMenuCtrl($scope, $http, Toggler, routeProvider) {

        $http.get('models/mainMenu.json').then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.menuItems = response.data;
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("http error");
            }
        )

        function routeIt (page) {
            routeProvider
                .when('/page1', {
                    url: "/page1",
                    templateUrl: 'views/page1.html',
                    controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
                })
                .when('/page2', {
                    url: "/page2",
                    templateUrl: 'views/page2.html',
                    controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
                })
        }

        $scope.itemClicked = function (item){
            Toggler.menuToggle();
            routeIt(item);
        }

    }
})();
```

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. Why would you deviate from documented way to use router along with `$location` service?

Comment: Just my brain dump in order to come up with a solution for my un-answered post [link(]http://stackoverflow.com/q/35043417/5047454)

Comment: router has numerous events you can subscribe to. Also new view means new controller instance.  What is higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well, when I click on an item from left drawer, the drawer should disappear and the page "linked" to this item appear. And if the page is already shown, then just hide the drawer. [link](https://github.com/Fred-J/students.git)

Comment: This is really trivial. Just use `ng-href` in links to do navigation and add `ng-click` on links to close drawer using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` on drawer container. Configure router as per docs

Answer (score 0):

Service providers aren't available for injection in run phase (i.e. anywhere but `provider` services and `config` blocks). It is possible to make route provider injectable and configure it after config phase,

```
app.config(function ($provide, $routeProvider) {
  $provide.value('$routeProvider', $routeProvider);
});
```

And controllers aren't the best places to implement any logic (e.g. route hot-plug).

Answer (score 0):

Ok you're using your routeProvider wrong you need to configure your routes inside `.config` blocks

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
       .when('/page1', {
             url: "/page1",
             templateUrl: 'views/page1.html',
             controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
       }
 })
```

If you want to change the url from your controller use `$location.path('/page1');` inside your controller.

Comment: Could you show how $location.path is used in a controller please? thx